Error when working with tests on qt5, CMake
I am trying to use QtTest, but I am getting the following error:
error: Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5Tests" with any of the following names: Qt5TestsConfig.cmake qt5tests-config.cmake Add the installation prefix of "Qt5Tests" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5Tests_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5Tests" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed. CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package)

According to information from other questions, it becomes clear that I am missing some package. However, I don't understand which one. I am working on qt5 with CMake.
Packages that are already attached:
libqt5quicktest5, libqt5test5, libqt6quicktest6, libqt6test6, libcppunit-1.15-0, libcpputest-dev, libcpptest1
This is the part of my Cmake file:
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    Widgets
    Tests
)
target_link_libraries(Test PRIVATE Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(Test PRIVATE Qt5::Tests)


Name of the component is Test, not Tests. The CMake file for it - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/Qt5Test/Qt5TestConfig.cmake - is part of qtbase5-dev package.
